# What difference does it make to include (or not include) a capture list in nonescaping closures?

Tags: swift

This is my code:

```
class Person { 
    let age: Int

    init(age: Int) { 
        self.age = age
    }

    func callAgePrinter() { 
        // THIS LINE
        AgePrinter.printAgeOf(person: { return self } )
    }
}

class AgePrinter {
    static func printAgeOf(person: () -> (Person)) { 
        print(person().age)
    }
}

Person(age: 1).callAgePrinter()
```

Notice the comment: `// THIS LINE`

I am able to transform this line:

```
AgePrinter.printAgeOf(person: { return self } )
```

To:

```
AgePrinter.printAgeOf(person: { [unowned self] in return self } )
```

The result of the code is the same.

I am wondering: for nonescaping closures (which apply for Swift 4.2 only at function declaration level), what is the use a capture list? It is guaranteed for nonescaping closures that after the method is ended in which the closure is (or may not) be called, the closure is gone and not stored.

Ofcourse, a retain cycle can still occur when storting the output of the closure in my example. However, a capture cycle does not prevent this.

**What difference does it make to include (or not include) a capture list in nonescaping closures?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is common to use capture lists for `self`, but that is not their only purpose. A capture list captures arbitrary values. And by "capture," I mean "makes its own shadow copy rather than closing over the value in its scope." Consider the following code:

```
var a = 10

let f: () -> Void = { print("f: \(a)") }

let g: () -> Void = { [a] in print("g: \(a)") }

a = 20
f()   // f: 20; using "a" from the local scope surrounding f()
g()   // g: 10; using "a" that was copied into g()
```

As a slightly more complex example, consider the following (incorrect) code where we accumulate some actions to perform, using some value that needs to increment from action to action:

```
var actions: [() -> Void] = []

var opId = 0
if someCase {
    opId += 1
    actions.append({ doSomethingWith(opId) })
}
if anotherCase {
    opId +=1
    actions.append({ doSomethingElseWith(opId) })
}
//...
actions.forEach { $0() }
```

This code is incorrect; all of the closures will have the same opId. However, if we add a capture list, we can resolve the problem:

```
actions.append({ [opId] in doSomethingWith(opId) })
```

Comment: Hmm ok, but this example shows escaping closures. Now variable `a` is stored inside the closures. With nonescaping closures this isn't possible (executing the closure at a later point). Do you have another example with nonescaping closures? Because I think with nonescaping closures, I can not quite get into the same situation as you described here.

Comment: The above code is not an escaping closure. It is called before the current scope is exited. (Escaping closures are called after the function returns; they "escape" their scope.) I don't know what you mean by "escaping" in this context.

Comment: I made a mistake, I thought stored closures are implicit escaping closures, but escaping closures only apply at function deceleration level (I think).

Comment: Escaping closures are any closures that escape their scope. So a function that returns a closure (`() -> () -> Void`) also creates an escaping closure, even though there's no requirement to decorate it with `@escaping`. And assigning a closure to a property in another example of escaping, which can happen without a function at all. `self.f = {...}`: the closure assigned to `f` has escaped since `self` will outlive the current method scope. But `let f = {...}` does not by itself cause an escape. It just gives the closure a name.

Comment: Are this two snippets equal: `var a = something; let f: () -> Void = { [a] in print(a)  }` and `var a = something; let _a = a; let f: () -> Void = { print(_a) }`. Or capture list does copying differs from just storing current value of `a` in some `let` "constant"?

Comment: @user28434 Your two examples are effectively the same. They even produce almost identical SIL (`swiftc -O -emit-sil`).

Answer (score 2):

Capture copies the information inside the variable inside a new one. I mean `[unowned self]` creates another `self` variable which is not actually a `self`.